# Cache-Control Headers

Tags: php, http, cache-control

I'm writing a small wrapper in PHP for the Cache-Control headers.  I wanted to get a few details straight before I commit to a particular implementation.

I'm aware of all the directives and what they do, but it seems like a few of them could conflict.  I'm assuming that if `no-cache` is present, than no other Cache-Control directive should be present (and also *not* set `Pragma: no-cache`, as it's actually a request header).

Does the presence of `s-maxage` imply `public`?  And a `private` directive should remove `public` as well as `s-maxage`.  Are there any caveats with setting `no-store`, `no-transform`, `must-revalidate` or `proxy-revalidate` in this manner?  Are there other directives that conflict with each other?

And would `no-cache` and the gang conflict with any non-cache-control directive, such as `Expires`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, even if you get all cache headers and directives theoretically right, whether or not the browsers and proxies do as they are told is another matter. I don't think there is a way around testing (which is painful). Especially with so many tablet and mobile devices around. http://www.procata.com/cachetest/ may help a bit. I am not aware of a reliable cache testing framework.

Then there is a certain confusion between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1 directives. Generally, backwards compatibility exists (but that should be tested as well). I would consider ignoring HTTP 1.0 directives entirely (which are: *Pragma: No-cache* and *Expires*) and focus on HTTP 1.1.

The hierarchy of the cache directives is explained in http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/. Some of your questions are answered there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at

http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-17.html

and, if that doesn't answer it, to send feedback to the HTTPbis Working Group.